# Error Cast to date failed for value in Nestjs Mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nestjs

I have the following code, and my goal is to set the createdAt to a new date when I pass false to status, but when I pass true to status, I want the date to remain unchanged, i.e., the date should remain the one that is there in the database. When I pass false to status, everything works fine, but when I pass true to status, I get the error below:

```
{
    "statusCode": 500,
    "message": "Cast to date failed for value \"todos.$[todo].createdAt\" (type string) at path \"createdAt\"",
    "error": "Internal Server Error"
}
```

Here is my toggle method:

```
  //toggle todo as completed true or false
  async toggleTodo(
    userId: string,
    data: ToggleTodoDto,
  ): Promise<{ todo: TodoEntity; message: string }> {
    try {
      const { childTodoId, todoId, status } = data;
      const todo = await this.todoModel
        .findOneAndUpdate(
          {
            _id: new ObjectId(todoId),
            userId: new ObjectId(userId),
          },
          {
            $set: {
              'todos.$[todo].isCompleted': status,
              // if status is false, set createdAt to new date otherwise leave the date as it is
              'todos.$[todo].createdAt': status
                ? 'todos.$[todo].createdAt'
                : new Date(),
            },
          },
          {
            arrayFilters: [{ 'todo._id': new ObjectId(childTodoId) }],
            new: true,
          },
        )
        .exec();
      if (!todo) throw new NotFoundException('To-Do not found');
      return {
        todo,
        message: 'To-Do toggled successfully',
      };
    } catch (error) {
      if (error instanceof NotFoundException)
        throw new NotFoundException(error.message);
      throw new InternalServerErrorException(error.message);
    }
  }
```

Here is my database's shema

```
@Schema(childTodoMongooseSchemaConfig)
class SingleTodoEntity {
  @Prop()
  todo: string;

  @Prop({ default: false })
  isCompleted: boolean;

  @Prop({ type: Date, default: Date })
  createdAt: Date;
}

@Schema(mongooseSchemaConfig)
export class TodoEntity {
  @Prop({ type: Types.ObjectId, ref: UserEntity.name })
  userId: string;

  @Prop()
  title?: string;

  @Prop([{ type: SingleTodoEntity }])
  @Type(() => SingleTodoEntity)
  todos: SingleTodoEntity[];
}
export const TodoSchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(TodoEntity);
export type TodoDocument = TodoEntity & Document;
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

One option is to update the query itself according to the `status`. Something like:

```
const setPart = {}
setPart['todos.$[todo].isCompleted'] = status
if (!status) {
  setPart['todos.$[todo].createdAt'] = new Date();
}
const todo = await this.todoModel
        .findOneAndUpdate(
          {
            _id: new ObjectId(todoId),
            userId: new ObjectId(userId),
          },
          {$set: setPart},
          {
            arrayFilters: [{ 'todo._id': new ObjectId(childTodoId) }],
            new: true,
          },
        ).exec();
```

Comment: WOW!!! @nimrod serok This answer works perfectly; I wish I could give you a thousand vote up. Thank you so much; you are a life saver.